# Where can I ask questions for technical data of a TV?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about a technical detail on a TV that I want to buy, namely *interpolation value*. Which site should I be using to ask for help?

Comment: Sadly for some odd reason, every single attempt at a consumer electronics site has failed.

Comment: @Blue My question basically boils down to what is meant by 'interpolation value' shown for the TV. Thanks, I'll ask on Video Production meta if it's allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If yours is a purely technical question about [motion interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_interpolation) and *not* a "[shopping recommendation](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-do-you-think-about-shopping-recommendations)" question, it *might* be [on-topic](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I get some results when I search for [interpolation value](https://video.stackexchange.com/search?tab=&q=interpolation+value&mixed=0) there. You may ensure whether your question is truly on-topic it by asking on [their meta](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/) first.